# No Module name pygame.base

Tags: python, opengl, multiprocessing, pygame, pyinstaller

I wrote my program to spawn a process of the main application. When I run the pyinstaller packaged exe it says `no Module name pygame.base`. But if I keep the app in the main thread it doesn't do that.

I need the process to detect closure, because GLUT doesn't have an event for the upper right hand exit button and I can't remove it unless I use full-screen. The program's threads hang and the app never closes. So the main thread checks to see if the process is running. If not, it closes the entire application. But all closure will hang if I only use the main thread.

I can soft exit from in-game events just fine. But I need a way to catch the X button. OR fix pyinstaller.

I've looked up a bunch of things getting pyinstaller to include everything. I used the OneDir option so I can see the files. I copied all dependencies from one that worked to the one that didn't without replacing the exe. It still had the import error.

Any insight would be nice. For now the X button is a hazard. I'm guessing multiprocessing doesn't work with pyinstaller all too well.

Comment: Please post some code that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The [x] button fires for me, when `event.type == pygame.QUIT` on windows.

Comment: I can only use that event if I use pygames window for OpenGL not GLUT. I stopped using pygame cause Its too slow. As is SDL.